# Using `new` on a mocked function with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock the return value when using `new` against a mocked function:

```
const myMock = jest.fn();
myMock.mockReturnValueOnce('some_string');
const result = new myMock();
```

The problem is that `new myMock()` returns `{}` (an empty object) instead of the return value I specify.

I looked in the documentation but couldn't find a different function to use. Is there a different function I can use to make the result when used with new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is any way to mock the result of `new myMock()` directly with the Jest API.

Instead, what I ended up doing was wrapping it in a function and passing along it's parameters. I also had to make sure the resulting value was an object (this is a JavaScript thing).

It ended up like this:

```
const mockedValue = { d: 'DUMMY' };
const mock = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mockedValue);
const myMock = (a, b) => mock(a, b); // a, b are parameters. Use more or less as needed
const result = new myMock(); // { d: 'DUMMY' }
```

The wrapper function is just a normal function, but when it is called with `new`, I'm able to instead return the result of my `mock` as the new value. I pass along the parameters that are used in order to make sure checks with `.toBeCalledWith()` work as expected.